# SecurityExceptions in GooglePlay services

Tags: java, android, crash, google-play-services, dexguard

After last update of our application we start getting tons of crashes like:

```
java.lang.SecurityException:  
Unable to find app for caller  
android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy@4752d050 (pid=24424) when binding service 
Intent {  
  act=com.google.android.location.internal.GoogleLocationManagerService.START  
  pkg=com.google.android.gms
}   at  
android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1465)   at  
android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1419)   at  
android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.bindService(ActivityManagerNative.java:3090)   at  
android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1696)    at  
android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1665)  at  
android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:517)     at  
com.google.android.gms.internal.zzlo.zzka(Unknown Source)
```

We using `dexguard` and all rules that was suggested by google added in obfuscation rules.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this problem?

Comment: At what point were you getting these crashes?  When calling a Play Services API, or what.